# Protomodular categories

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, intuition, big-picture

The axioms for abelian categories are nice and clear. The axioms for protomodular categories - and therefore semi-abelian categories - are beyond me entirely. I'm looking for a breakdown of the definition and a discussion of its components along with some intuition. A reference would be great too. (Bourceux & Bourn's book only gets to protomodular categories on page 227, which is.. not optimal.)

***Update:*** For a nice characterization of semi-abelian (and homological) categories, see Hartl & Loiseau's [*A working Mathematician's Definition of Semi-Abelian Categories*](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0905.4941v2.pdf).

Comment: This is a pretty specialized area that I don't know much about, but it looks like the [nlab article](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/protomodular+category) has a pretty nice high-level discussion, including a slogan (a protomodular category is one with a good notion of normal subobject), an example which is not homological/semiabelian (topological groups), and a nice list of consequences. If you want more detail, you will probably have to roll up your sleeves and read the book. I don't know how the book is organized, but you might be able to skip the earlier parts of the book.

Comment: Look at page 242 Prop. 3.1.24 and page 267 Prop. 4.1.4. With some assumptions you can "avoid" the fibration of points entirely.

Comment: A finitely complete category is protomodular if and only if the 'converse' of the "pullback pasting lemma" works with the middle arrow a split epi. See for example Bourn, Gran "Regular, protomodular, and abelian categories"